# Unable to work with lines i csv created by export-csv

Tags: powershell, export-csv

After running this script:

```
# Input path
$input_path = 'C:\Users\larry\Pictures\2003'

# Export file
$documents_export_file = 'C:\Users\larry\Documents\Temp\ffmpeg\fullnames.csv'

# Copy-to folder
$copy_to = "C:\Users\larry\Documents\Temp\ffmpeg\movies"


# List filenames in $documents_export_file
Get-ChildItem -Attributes !Directory -Path $input_path -Recurse -force | select-object -Property fullName | Export-Csv $documents_export_file

# Copy the files listed in $documents_export_file to $copy_to folder
get-content $documents_export_file | Foreach-Object { copy-item -Path $_ -Destination $copy_to}
```

I get the following error:

```
copy-item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '"C' does not exist.
At line:18 char:55
+ ... ort_file | Foreach-Object { copy-item -Path $_ -Destination $copy_to}
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ("C:String) [Copy-Item], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
 
copy-item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '"C' does not exist.
At line:18 char:55
+ ... ort_file | Foreach-Object { copy-item -Path $_ -Destination $copy_to}
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ("C:String) [Copy-Item], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

As far as I can figure out, it has something to do with my Export-Csv, bur I can´t figure it out.
Please give me a hand.

Comment: Start by checking the value of `$_` and `$copy_to` in your loop. Insert `Write-Host "path: '$_' Copy To: '$copy_to'";` or similar so you can see the values.

Comment: What Powershell version are you using? Why not use the `-File` parameter?

Comment: [1] Add switch `-NoTypeInformation` to the `Export-Csv` command to prevent extra info above the header line. [2] When reading back a CSV file, use `Import-Csv`, NOT `Get-Content` because that is a cmdlet to read a text file as string array.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to export the list of files to CSV in the first place - assign the output from `Get-ChildItem` to a variable instead, and then pipe the contents directly to `Copy-Item`:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Attributes !Directory -Path $input_path -Recurse -Force

$files |Copy-Item -Destination $copy_to
```